# Dynamically pull current month+next two months from Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, timezone

I'm trying to pull the current month and next two months dynamically in Oracle SQL. The purpose is to use this in an email which refers to these months. Instead of manually changing this email I thought it would be easier to have it automated via SQL. Ideally it would appear with the fields of

```
CURRENT_MONTH   SECOND_MONTH    THIRD_MONTH
```

and results as
May June July

One last thing, needs to be in TIME ZONE 'Australia/Sydney

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following sql:

```
select
   to_char(SYSTIMESTAMP at time zone 'Australia/Sydney', 'MONTH') as CURRENT_MONTH
  ,to_char(add_months(SYSTIMESTAMP at time zone 'Australia/Sydney', 1), 'MONTH') as SECOND_MONTH
  ,to_char(add_months(SYSTIMESTAMP at time zone 'Australia/Sydney', 2), 'MONTH') as THIRD_MONTH
from dual
;
```

Comment: Glad to help.  Please mark the answer as correct if possible.